# WPF - UI locking up during Database operations (EF6, async/await)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, async-await, entity-framework-6

So I'm working on a WPF Application that is performing some database operations on startup and recently decided to add a SplashScreen containing an "isIndeterminate" ProgressBar as a visual indicator that the application is performing background tasks.

However I can't get it to work without freezing the UI thread. First time working with `async` / `await` so help is much appreciated. (using EF6 & locally installed MS SQL Server 2019 in case that's relevant)

Here's my code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private const int minSplashTime = 2000;

    protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        SplashScreenWindow splash = new SplashScreenWindow();
        splash.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        await AsyncDbTask();

        timer.Stop();

        // Wait remainingTime if minSplashTime is not reached yet
        int remainingTime = minSplashTime - (int)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (remainingTime > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(remainingTime);
        }

        splash.Close();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private async Task AsyncDbTask()
    {
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            // PERFORMING DB OPERATIONS HERE
            // [...]

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try `Task.Run` for everything in the using-statement including the using

Comment: Does your database supports asynchronous operations? What database do you use?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm using a freshly installed MS SQL Server 2019. It should support async operations at base configuration as far as i know.

Comment: Welcome, using ```await``` blocks your UI thread because it still executes on the UI thread. ```await``` does not automatically execute your method on a different thread. As suggested by Ackdari, you'll have to use ```Task.Run``` in this case.

Comment: @imsmn that is not completely true, true async IO would free the UI-thread to do other stuff. That not CPU bound work is still executed by the UI-thread is a feature so you can interact with UI components.

Comment: Okay got it. I simply replaced ```await AsyncDbTask;``` with ```await Task.Run(AsyncDbTask);``` and it works like a charme now. Thanks @Ackdari & @imsmn

Comment: @Ackdari I'm not sure if I understood correctly but by 'true async IO' you - roughly said - mean that ```db.SaveChangesAsync``` takes care of ```Task.Run```?

Comment: What database provider are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a method returns a `Task<T>` does not mean it actually is run asynchronously. Some database engines does not support asynchronous queries and will run everything synchronous. And even if your database does support true async queries it does not necessarily mean that it cannot complete synchronously or that it will not do a significant amount of work on the caller thread.

A workaround would be to use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0)